# How to make full text search from client side using jquery?

Tags: jquery

I want to make full text search from client side using Jquery. Found some solutions but they all are giving exact match.

I want to perform Boolean search on the data. The data is present on client side in tree format.

Eg. If I put required search filter on search engine, it will show me exact match with relevant data, that same search want to perform on client side.

**Tried** - http://www.redotheweb.com/2013/05/15/client-side-full-text-search-in-css.html
it gives exact match. but if I add multiple words in search field it fails. Finding for better solution.

Anybody is having idea how to perform this kind of search ? or knowing any plugin, then please suggest for best.
Thanks in advance. :)

Comment: Show us your code

Answer (score 2):

you can use FuseJs. of course its not a jquery plugin but a javascript library.
its using fuzzy search in the background to find what you want.

FuseJs is a Lightweight fuzzy-search, in JavaScript, with zero dependencies.

you can take a look at [Demo and usage here](http://fusejs.io/)

and here is the quick look at the library.

lets grab this array of objects as our model :

```
var list = [
     {
        title: "Old Man's War",
        author: {
          firstName: "John",
          lastName: "Scalzi"
        }
     },
     {
        title: "The Lock Artist",
        author: {
          firstName: "Steve",
          lastName: "Hamilton"
        }
     },
     {
        title: "HTML5",
        author: {
          firstName: "Remy",
          lastName: "Sharp"
        }
     }
]
```

lets search in these array and find items with the key:

```
var options = {
  shouldSort: true,
  threshold: 0.6,
  location: 0,
  distance: 100,
  maxPatternLength: 32,
  minMatchCharLength: 1,
  keys: [
    "title",
    "author.firstName"
]
};
var fuse = new Fuse(list, options);
var result = fuse.search("The Lock Artist"); //this can be read from an input
```

the result of this would be :

```
[
  {
    "title": "The Lock Artist",
    "author": {
      "firstName": "Steve",
      "lastName": "Hamilton"
    }
  }
]
```

there is a lot of options that you can see in a [official website](http://fusejs.io/).

***Note for better result :***

for better result and more exact matches you should change Threshold and Distance option.

**Threshold :**

> At what point does the match algorithm give up. A threshold of 0.0 requires a perfect match (of both letters and location), a threshold of 1.0 would match anything.

**Distance :**

> Determines how close the match must be to the fuzzy location (specified by location). An exact letter match which is distance characters away from the fuzzy location would score as a complete mismatch. A distance of 0 requires the match be at the exact location specified, a distance of 1000 would require a perfect match to be within 800 characters of the location to be found using a threshold of 0.8.

For example in the official website when you search for word "Steve" you will get "Jeeves" result too. as I said we should change distance and threshold.

in this case settings would be :

Threshold: 0.2

Distance: 0

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan its just I'm not as lazy as you are :) I wanted to give him more information about what it is exactly not GO FIND BY YOUR SELF.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/18337779)

Comment: @thewaywewere I edited my answer and add an example of how it works

Comment: @M.R.Safari I tried the link you have mentioned, I added keyword "Steve" in a search text n output comes as,

Comment: `[
  {
    "item": {
      "title": "The Lock Artist",
      "author": {
        "firstName": "Steve",
        "lastName": "Hamilton"
      }
    },
    "score": 0.2
  },
  {
    "item": {
      "title": "Right Ho Jeeves",
      "author": {
        "firstName": "P.D",
        "lastName": "Woodhouse"
      }
    },
    "score": 0.49
  },
  {
    "item": {
      "title": "The Code of the Wooster",
      "author": {
        "firstName": "P.D",
        "lastName": "Woodhouse"
      }
    },
    "score": 0.5900000000000001
  },`

Comment: Unwanted objects are also coming into search. Do you have any idea how to avoid this.

Comment: @SwapnaliHadawale take a look at my edited post. (Note for better result)

Comment: @SwapnaliHadawale for word "Steve". Try Threshold 0.2 and distance 0. you will get the exact match.

Comment: @SwapnaliHadawale please consider mark my answer as a final answer if it was helpful :)